# how to filter data by using date picker

Tags: angularjs, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0GSy.png)Please check below code.angular inbuilt filter working fine. need to filter data by using date picker Please help me for the same. screenshot attached for the reference

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped ">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>RECEIPT NO</td>
        <td>DATE</td>
        <td>NAME</td>
        <td>PLACE</td>
        <td>MEDIATOR NAME</td>
        <td>INTEREST RATE</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="rec in records |filter:searchText |filter:  date_picker">
        <td>{{rec.RECEIPT_NO}}</td>
        <td>{{rec.DATE}}</td>
        <td>{{rec.NAME}}</td>
        <td>{{rec.PLACE}}</td>
        <td>{{rec.MEDIATOR_NAME}}</td>
        <td>{{rec.INTEREST_RATE}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Angular Code-------------------**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("reportingCtrl", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.records = [];

    $scope.ajayxCall = function() {
      var url = "assets/API/api.json";
      $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        $scope.records = response.data

      });
    };
    $scope.ajayxCall();
    $scope.today = function() {
      $scope.dt = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();
    $scope.clear = function() {
      $scope.dt = null;
    };
    $scope.toggleMin = function() {
      $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleMin();
    $scope.open = function($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();
      $event.stopPropagation();
      $scope.opened = true;
    };
    $scope.dateOptions = {
      formatYear: 'yy',
      startingDay: 1
    };
    $scope.formats = ['yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
    $scope.getTime = function() {
      time.getTime()
        .success(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $scope.records = data.records;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log('error!');
        });
    };
  });
```

Comment: Where is the field date_picker in your code. Is it one of the element present in the list that you are iterating ?

Comment: you need to filter data by using date picker means filter by date?

Comment: yes filter by date

Comment: <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" datepicker-popup="{{format}}"></div>

Comment: If you want to filer by any field you can add it during the iteration. I am not sure if you are looking for anything else
<tr ng-repeat="rec in records | filter:  date_picker">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom filter for date like following

```
.filter('DateFilter', function() {
  return function(dataArray, date) {
    if (!dataArray) {
      return;
    } else if (!date) {
      return dataArray;
    } else {
      return dataArray.filter(function(item) {
        var recordDate = new Date(item.DATE);
        var term = recordDate.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear() &&
          recordDate.getMonth() === date.getMonth() &&
          recordDate.getDate() === date.getDate();
        return term;
      });
    }
  };
})
```

You can call this filter like

```
<tr ng-repeat="rec in records |filter:searchText | DateFilter:  date_picker">
```

Comment: not working sir,any other way to to filter data by date picker in angular js

Comment: Did you just copied it or used according to your variable names, can you tell me any errors while using this filter